# Is it possible to have React handle rendering an object as a child?

Tags: reactjs

```
<SomeComponent>
    {someValue}
</SomeComponent>
```

If `someValue` is of type `object`, React crashes. I was wondering if I could make it so React won't crash when trying to render that object, possibly tell it to try to`JSON.stringify` or just put some arbitrary text instead of just crashing.

Comment: Are you looking for general solution or you just need that for debuging?

Comment: you can't put object in a component tree

Comment: @ulou I guess general but ideally this would never happen in prod with proper communications & backwards compatibility between UI and API. But as we're in early development the API we integrate with is always evolving too where they might convert some field to be an object suddenly and our app crashes. I'd rather that field just not render properly and not deal with checking types for every value, adding a bunch of error boundaries or doing client side validation of API res. So I was wondering if there was some hook where I can be like if you get type Object do/show xyz instead of crashing.